# JavaScript substraction function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made a simple html and JS click counter website but I cant get the minus function to work.
Heres my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Tally Counter
        </title>
        <Link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var add = (function(){
                var counter = 0;
                return function (){return counter+=1;}
            })();
            function addCount(){
                document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = add();
            }
            var minus = (function(){
                return function (){return counter-=1;}
            })();
            function minusCount(){
                document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = minus();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Counter
        </h1>
        <p id='carrier'> 0 </p>
        <button onclick="addCount()">Add count</button>
        <button onclick="minusCount()">Lower count</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Only the lower count button doesn't work. Can someone help and tell me if I am missing somethnig?

Comment: `counter` is defined locally inside the `add` function. Hence, it can only be used inside `add`. Declare it outside, where it will be accessible by both functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `counter` outside your `add` method.

[edit] You defined your counter variable inside a function, so it can only be reached from inside said function. By moving it outside, every function can reach (and modify) the variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Tally Counter
        </title>
        <Link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var counter = 0; // here
            var add = (function(){
                // var counter = 0; // not here
                return function (){return counter+=1;}
            })();
            function addCount(){
                document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = add();
            }
            var minus = (function(){
                return function (){return counter-=1;}
            })();
            function minusCount(){
                document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = minus();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Counter
        </h1>
        <p id='carrier'> 0 </p>
        <button onclick="addCount()">Add count</button>
        <button onclick="minusCount()">Lower count</button>
    </body>
</html>
```